# Tweepy stream when a user follows you

Tags: tweepy

I need to use a stream listener that is triggered when the authenticated user receives a follow.  I know this is possible in tweepy, just am unaware how.

Comment: you can simply keep a check on the followers count, and any increase in that figure would be an indication of a new follower and you can followback, if would like to

Comment: @Anmol_uppal I would do that, but that event can only be fired 15 times in a 15-minute window (im thinking len(api.follower_ids) etc)

Comment: No there is a better way , what is the need of fetching all the id's if you only need to count them ? try using `followers_count`